# How to handle google chrome external protocol when your software is on wine?

Tags: wine, google-chrome, browser, xdg-open

My problem is this: I have a software installed with Wine (Brain Explorer 2, [it's free](http://human.brain-map.org/static/brainexplorer)); certain functions of this software requires using the browser (in this case google chrome; firefox isn't an option since this needs flash player...). Then, Explorer opens browser. When you are browsing in the website, there is an option **that loads data from browser to software**, then the browser ask for external protocol for **aibe:link** (aibe is for Allen Institute Brain Explorer, I suppose), that ends on launch xdg-open, which as far as I know it handles the default apps.

[image: Basically this is what happens]

So I guess must try config the default apps for aibe links, but honestly I'm lost. The most I figured is that is similar to magnet links with torrent. Of course on windows there is no such a problem since is designed for it. But how I make this work here on Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure, here is the [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9yVQX3HB5ddZ1NlTjlYNHJEMHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: (just in case didn't noticed, click on "link" to see my reg on google drive :P)

Comment: Se agradece la ayuda, buen hombre :)

Comment: This happens: `$ winebrowser aibe://human.brain-map.org/mri_viewer/data/heatmap/probe_values?atlas=351&resolution=samples&probes=1036443&selectedDonor=9861&well=2569&colormap=redgreen&exprRange=-6,6
[1] 9805
[2] 9806
[3] 9807
[4] 9809
[5] 9810
[6] 9811
[2]   Hecho                   resolution=samples
[3]   Hecho                   probes=1036443
[4]   Hecho                   selectedDonor=9861
[5]-  Hecho                   well=2569
[6]+  Hecho                   colormap=redgreen`

Comment: Basically, it just opens the data but nothing happens.

Comment: The data opens on the program, just as a magnet link opens a torrent software (link on browser --> software). And if it is a wine software, I don't know how to tell browser, or xdg-open, to open aibe link on BE2.

Comment: and I did the winebrowser things, but nothing different happened.

Comment: Also, tried installing a windows browser on Ubuntu (for instance firefox), and opening the aibe link from there, but also nothing happened :(

Comment: First 30 sec [of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aUWdKvSIG0) shows what I expect this software does on Ubuntu

Comment: What is the full path to the Brain Explorer executable? (i.e. `/home/pepito/.wine/dosdevices/drive_c/Program files/Blah/Blep/Brainexplorer.exe`)

Answer (score 3):

**Making it work:**

1. Run `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/allen-brainexplorer.desktop`
2. A text editor will open up. Paste the following contents on it:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Brain Explorer 2
   Exec=wine "%ProgramFiles%\Allen Institute\Brain Explorer 2\BrainExplorer2.exe" "/url" "%u"
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/aibe;
   ```
3. Save the file and close the text editor.
4. Run the following command to "install" the newly-created file in the system:

   ```
   xdg-desktop-menu install ~/.local/share/applications/allen-brainexplorer.desktop
   ```
5. When the browser prompts you how to handle this type of link, choose **Run Application**.

---

**How I got it:**

I've installed Brain Explorer 2 on a Windows XP VM so I could open the regedit and find that key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\aibe\shell\open\command
```

That key had this content:

```
"C:\Program files\Allen Institute\Brain Explorer 2\BrainExplorer2.exe" /url "%1"
```

This means that the `/url` option allows to pass the URL to BrainExplorer. Example:

```
wine "/home/$USER/.wine/dosdevices/drive_c/Program files/Allen Institute/Brain Explorer 2/BrainExplorer2.exe" /url "aibe://human.brain-map.org/mri_viewer/data/heatmap/probe_values?atlas=351&resolu‌​tion=samples&probes=1036443&selectedDonor=9861&well=2569&colormap=redgreen&exprRa‌​nge=-6,6"
```

Comment: For instance, I replaced the Exec line of .desktop file with ** "sh -c "cd /home/UserFolder/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Allen\ Institute/Brain\ Explorer\ 2; wine BrainExplorer2.exe" "/url" "%u" **. Then followed the steps. The browser shows BrainExplorer2 to open aibe:link, and the program opens correctly but does not load any microarray data as it does in Windows :/

Comment: Also tried from Firefox and Chrome, there wasn't a difference.

Comment: So in my guess, what is working is xdg-open, which directs aibe links by default to BrainExplorer2. But isn't showing the data that is supposed to show as in Windows. Something is missing.

Comment: Or maybe my exec line is wrong somehow XD

Comment: Try running this on a terminal:  `wine "/home/$USER/.wine/dosdevices/drive_c/Program files (x86)/Allen Institute/Brain Explorer 2/BrainExplorer2.exe" /url "aibe://human.brain-map.org/mri_viewer/data/heatmap/probe_values?atlas=351&resolu‌​tion=samples&probes=1036443&selectedDonor=9861&well=2569&colormap=redgreen&exprRa‌​nge=-6,6"`

Comment: Oh I forgot to answer. Well essentially nothing different happened; I tried to execute wine BE2.exe /url "aibe:link" (with quotes and without). [Sadly, this happens](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9yVQX3HB5ddVmVRMnlpMVE5dms/view?usp=sharing). I really don't get it.

Comment: I suspected that when it says "could't interpret command"means I was doing wrongly the command syntax. So, tried with **wine BE2.exe /url"aibe:link"** (no spaces btwn /url"aibe:link"). The program is launched, but program crashes when attempting to open data from link ("wine: Unhandled page fault on write access to 0x67756269 at address 0x7bc4fb96 (thread 0021), starting debugger...". [There is a dump here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9yVQX3HB5ddYnRQZXdDbDV3Zms/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @zx_k9: Are you sure of the syntax? On the regedit there is a space between `/url` and the URL... However, I don't know anything of wine (and less of the Windows internals and debugging). I can't help you here. However, 2 comments above this, you post a screenshot on gDrive where you forgot to put quotes on the URI (`aibe`link) I thing that you may put this quoted and with a space bethween `/url` and the URI.

Comment: Ok, I found something. I did the syntax exactly as you did, and as previously said the program couldn't interpret the /url command. I went to check regedit and the key was **"C:\Program files\Allen Institute\Brain Explorer 2\BrainExplorer2.exe" /dde"**. Our keys seems to be different for some reason. So, replacing with /dde on .desktop file the program don't throw any error about interpreting aibe:link, neither on terminal and apparently the program open rightly. But even with that, program do not open data, just starts normally. By the way, why "%u" instead of "%1" on desktop file you made?

Comment: So, again I'm confused. I was checking this [about regedit key's and ddexec...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: But, is the regedit key read when `xdg-open` runs? :-/

Comment: My mistake (again). Seems /dde key handles other kind of things. Geez, I will install BE2 on a windows machine and copy the entire registry to look up for something... anyway, still cannot edit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to include the aibe key. [According to winehq](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/using-regedit) it is a link to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. Oh geez I feel I'm throwing garbage ideas. Really appreciate the patience :)